# Is there a way to modify the timestamps of multiple git commits?

Tags: git, github

For a few days I was using a computer with a wrongly set clock (without realising) and made a bunch of commits that now have the wrong timestamps. I'd like to know if it's possible to bring these timestamps forward by a set amount (2 weeks).

The commits are all sequential and I've already pushed them to Github.

I presume I'd need a script to do this (if it's possible at all) but I don't know where to start.

Comment: If the changes are all ready pushed trying to rewrite history will case a lot of problems.

Comment: `git filter-branch --env-filter`